# heroku giveing method not allowed in node js

Tags: node.js

I tried to post method in ajax request Method Not Allowed in js and give me Status Code 4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxcBt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the incorrect url for your site, as stated in the log message your url is https://morning-crag-28829.herokuapp.com